# Force close due to switch case method?

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.upArrow:
        upSound.start();

        En_description.setText("\"Straight Ahead\"");
        break;

    case R.id.downArrow:
        downSound.start();

        En_description.setText("\"Down\"");
        break;

    case R.id.rightArrow:
        rightSound.start();

        En_description.setText("\"Right\"");
        break;

    case R.id.leftArrow:
        leftSound.start();

        En_description.setText("\"Left\"");
        break;
    default: 

    }
}
```

The code is simple when I press on an arrow it types the direction of it and plays sound 
for some reason it works sometime and other times I get a force close  HELP 
Thanks this is the log

```
05-24 17:52:20.384: W/dalvikvm(343): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-24 17:52:20.394: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.aboutera.learnArabic.Directions.onClick(Directions.java:77)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 17:52:20.414: I/dalvikvm(343): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-24 17:52:20.414: E/dalvikvm(343): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
05-24 17:52:22.534: I/Process(343): Sending signal. PID: 343 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your logcat may help to get Exception that causes Force close

Comment: exiting due to uncaught exception 05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.NullPointerException 05-24 17:52:20.404: E/AndroidRuntime(343)

See Bradford2000 's answer

Comment: Whatever code you have at line 77 is what is causing the problem. I suspect there is an object you are accessing there that is null.

Comment: upSound = MediaPlayer.create(Directions.this, R.raw.up_sound);
   downSound = MediaPlayer.create(Directions.this, R.raw.down_sound);
   rightSound = MediaPlayer.create(Directions.this, R.raw.right_sound);
   leftSound = MediaPlayer.create(Directions.this, R.raw.left_sound);

Comment: Sorry if this is not an answer. In my case, after some hard work days I saw nothing on the screen, and it resulted in [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30019)... Hope you'll find out your silution  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to verify that upSound, downSound, leftSound, rightSound are all initialized(not null) before using them

```
if (upSound != null)
  upSound.start();
```

do for downSound, leftSound, rightSound also

You can initialize the sounds on the fly to make sure if the sound is null it gets played anyways..

```
  if (upSound == null)
     upSound = MediaPlayer.create(Directions.this, R.raw.up_sound);
  upSound.start();
```

Additionally, your textView `En_description` may also be null which could cause this crash as well.
Make sure wherever you are retrieving `En_description` (using findViewById) it is completing successfully

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your issue, but you might try doing a null check on v before doing v.getId().

```
if (v != null)
{
    // Do switch statement
}
```

Comment: unless he's manually calling the onClick "v" will never be null. its likely one of the upSound, downSound, objects being null or En_description is null

Comment: upSound = MediaPlayer.create(Directions.this, R.raw.up_sound);
   downSound = MediaPlayer.create(Directions.this, R.raw.down_sound);

Comment: The thing is it works and sometimes plays all the sounds normally but it seems if i clicked on the arrows in some pattern the app will force close

Comment: Do you set the upSound, downSound,etc = null when you release it once the playing stops?

Comment: no I don't set it to null I don't do a release at all actually